# Math.random() Javascript - Percentage and weight

Tags: javascript, math, ecmascript-6, percentage

I have an issue where I need to a have a percentage of calls that record, the system doesn't allow to just set that. So in my code I need to calculate it and then say for the 20% don't record.

Someone suggested using the Math.Random() function to do this and it should balance out but I cannot see how a random number generation.

so:

```
var desiredrecordpercentage = 80

var percentageCheck = Math.random()*100;
if (percentageCheck >= desiredrecordpercentage){

    disable recording;

}
```

I just don't see how that number would balance out per 100 calls, can it generate the same number twice within a 100 calls?  Or does it work through 100 then start again?

Comment: Can you show us wider code context and sample input along with desired output?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers

Comment: You can expect random numbers in the range [0..100]. If you pick a sample of 100 from the generator, then you (a) have to expect duplicates and (2) can't expect to see each number from the range in the result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: In general this should work, but most random generators will work best if used on a bigger number of tries, or calls in your case. It should even out.

Comment: If you have no means to ensure the pRNG produces uniformly distributed numbers then...I'm not sure what you can do. Usually you either trust a pRNG works or you don't. In the latter case, you look for one you trust. But if you've no way to verify, then you can't trust any. Given this is a widely used random number generator, I'd advise you to just trust it. If it was broken, it'd surely be reported by now. And fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I need something to happen based on a fixed probability, I usualy deal with a float point between 0 and 1, which is the same way `Math.random()` outputs a random value.

I have re-written your program to accommodate probabilities, but there is nothing wrong in working with percentages if you like. I just think multiplying by 100 is not that useful and it does not make the program more readable (at least for me).

There is one excellent video I watched a long time ago, that describes this very concept.

[Probability Basics - The Nature of Code By Daniel Shiffman (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frh0coyRmJQ&vl=en)

```
var desiredRecord = 0.8;   // 1: record everything, 
                           // 0: record nothing

var check = Math.random();  // check will be anywhere between 0 and 1

if (check > desiredRecord) { // will be true if check is between 0.81 and 0.99
                             // but false if check is below 0.8 
                             // which is more probable since 80 is the
                             // majority or the percentile

    disable_recording();

}
```

The above code will work and most of the time, `disable_recording()` won't get called, since most likely, the `random()` function will output values less than 0.8. But occasionally (20% of the time) the function will get called.

Comment: I am going to give this one a go.  See how it pans out using just the 0 - 1, using that wider range worries me.  I will do some testing on it.  Thanks everyone

Comment: @RussellHeaney multiplying by a constant is not really an issue. `0.8 * 100 > x * 100` and `0.8 > x` would have identical results for any value of `x`. Although the multiplication is not really relevant. The only reason to do that is if you are getting the percentage from a user (e.g., config or something) in which case it's more natural for people to type `80` for `80%` even if `0.8` expresses the exact same idea.